# Rectangle JavaFx Change color dynamic

Tags: javafx

I am implementing one application to draw rectangle, but now I need help to change color of my rectangles, I have this implementation:

```
    Pane root = new Pane();
    int qtd = 10;
    NumberBinding rectsAreaSize = Bindings.min(root.heightProperty(), root.widthProperty());
    Text texto = new Text("Matriz C");
    texto.setUnderline(true);
    texto.setLayoutX(150);
    texto.setLayoutY(400);

    for (int x = 8; x < qtd + 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 8; y < qtd + 8; y++) {
            Rectangle retangulo3 = new Rectangle();
            retangulo3.setStrokeWidth(2);
            retangulo3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

            retangulo3.xProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.multiply(x).divide(qtd * 2.5));
            retangulo3.yProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.multiply(y).divide(qtd * 2.5));

            retangulo3.heightProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.divide(qtd * 2.5));
            retangulo3.widthProperty().bind(retangulo3.heightProperty());

            retangulo3.setFill(Color.GREENYELLOW);

            root.getChildren().add(retangulo3);
        }
    }


        root.getChildren().add(texto);

        Text texto1 = new Text("Matriz A");

        texto1.setUnderline(true);
        texto1.setLayoutX(1200);
        texto1.setLayoutY(200);

        for (int x = 30; x < qtd + 30; x++) {
            for (int y = 2; y < qtd + 2; y++) {
                Rectangle retangulo1 = new Rectangle();
                retangulo1.setStrokeWidth(2);
                retangulo1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

                retangulo1.xProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.multiply(x).divide(qtd * 2.5));
                retangulo1.yProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.multiply(y).divide(qtd * 2.5));

            //retangulo.setHeight(10);
                //retangulo.setWidth(10);
                retangulo1.heightProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.divide(qtd * 2.5));
                retangulo1.widthProperty().bind(retangulo1.heightProperty());

                retangulo1.setFill(Color.WHITE);

                root.getChildren().add(retangulo1);
            }
        }

        root.getChildren().add(texto1);

        Text texto2 = new Text("Matriz B");

        texto2.setUnderline(true);
        texto2.setLayoutX(1200);
        texto2.setLayoutY(500);


        for (int x = 30; x < qtd + 30; x++) {
            for (int y = 13; y < qtd + 13; y++) {

                Rectangle retangulo2 = new Rectangle();
                retangulo2.setStrokeWidth(2);
                retangulo2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

                retangulo2.xProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.multiply(x).divide(qtd * 2.5));
                retangulo2.yProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.multiply(y).divide(qtd * 2.5));

            //retangulo.setHeight(10);
                //retangulo.setWidth(10);
                retangulo2.heightProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.divide(qtd * 2.5));
                retangulo2.widthProperty().bind(retangulo2.heightProperty());

                retangulo2.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                root.getChildren().add(retangulo2);
            }
        }

        root.getChildren().add(texto2);


        palco.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
        palco.show();

    }
```

Now I wanna make one superinduce of values and change my rectangle colors like a matriz multiplication, so I am lost in my code because when I create rectangles I have a lot of instances of objects, in the same pane I have three squares of rectangles, how could I make to change the of color of (x,y) like a dinamic thing ? How could I make to resize my image with another dimensions?

Comment: I do not understand your problem very well ... You would be trying to dynamically change the colors of your rectangles as an event happens? Maybe you should look rgb static method of the class Color. You will be able to choose a range of color you want with greater control. Knowing a little math, you can calculate the desired color as your rectangles are produced. I do not know if this is quite what you want. If you have questions or this does not help you, please comment here, and I will try other alternatives.

Comment: Hi thanks for your attention to my problem, well my problem is ilustrate one matrix multiplication, based on my posted code I need get matrix A x matrix B = matrix C, and I want put in execution time line[0] in matrix A with red color and in the same time matrix B column[0] with red color too and more..put in matrix C position [0,0] with red color...and make it to all my rectangle, but with another colors along time of animation.

Comment: In my code I am using the color class..xD

Comment: [something like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3Q4BN7e72I)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well .. Regarding the positioning logic of your rectangles that will be one thing you should calculate it. If you know the mathematical logic, you can solve it. After all, we're here to handle on the language itself.

With respect to how your rectangles are moved from point A to a point B, for this you can use the library of JavaFX animations. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CIHHAACG) to learn about animation (if you do not know). Take advantage and please take a look at the JavaFX documentation for all classes mentioned in the link. Read each one to gain a better understanding.

Note: If you are still novice, or have studied JavaFX from another source, you can learn a lot about JavaFX (2.x) on [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/). But I think you already know it, right?

Well .. With respect to animate colors in JavaFX, there is a great example of how this can be done in the demo program called [Ensemble](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). You can find it in the part where it is mentioned "JavaFX Samples Demos and Downloads", below.

Moreover, keep in mind that the library of JavaFX animations (mainly [keyFrame](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html), [KeyValue](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html), and [TimeLine](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/Timeline.html)) allows you to create animations of any [bean JavaFX property](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm). You can set your own JavaFX properties for some end, and then animate them following the way you want. In the animation translational demonstrated in your video, you can use a single Timeline object to perform the movement of all rectangles, and also the change of color of each.

To the desired motion of your elements, use existing layoutXY properties in Node class. Do not place anything with translateXY properties because they were made to give small final adjustments on a Node object position. The layoutXY properties are properties that define fixed positions. While you define layoutXY, you may end up using a transition animation in your program that precisely handles translateXY property of your Node objects. This is why you use LayoutXY for positioning.

With the logic of your program (the math), and the tips that I passed you, I believe you can easily solve your problem. If you still have question about something, please do not be shy to ask. My intention at the end of all is to help you.

Good luck on your projects. :)